# ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database (sql:/root/.pki/nssdb): NSS error code: -8023

Tags: software-installation

My system is Ubuntu 12.04, I want to run *nwjs*.
First I downloaded *nwjs* from  https://nwjs.io/

```
#tar xvf nwjs-v0.31.4-linux-ia32.tar.gz -C /usr/local/src 
#cd /usr/local/src/nwjs-v0.31.4-linux-ia32 x
#./nw 
ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database (sql:/root/.pki/nssdb): NSS er ror code: -8023
```

What does that mean？

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (released 2012.April with 5 years of supported life) is well past EOL & thus off-topic on this site unless you need help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  If you are using 12.04 ESM (still supported), it too is off-topic on this site

Comment: thank you for your reply.I try to use a high version（such as ubuntu 14.04 ） still has the problem. I suspect that is caused by nss.  Who encountered this problem ？

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it is an abandoned question.